# Getting document path in Basic in LibreOffice macro

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-basic, openoffice-base, libreoffice-base, libreoffice-basic

I know that this question has already been answered but the given solution doesn't work for me. The given solution is:

```
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim Path$
oDoc = ThisComponent
Path$ = oDoc.getURL()
```

Actually this returns an empty string ("") for me. Is there something I missed?

I'm on LibreOffice 4.3.1.2 on Kubuntu 12.04.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you run this?

```
If oDoc.HasLocation() Then
  Print "The Document URL is " & oDoc.getURL()
Else
  Print "The document has not yet been stored"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It **works perfectly if I compile the macro**, it doesn't work if I debug the uncompiled macro.

Answer (score 0):

of course, because the debug environment Parent is not the same then your Document Parent.